# In magento got a fatal error while creating new coustmers

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento-1.8

I have getting a fatal error while creating a new order in

```
Sales->Orders->create new order
```

**Fatal error:** Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3072 bytes) in `/home/deeplovi/public_html/magento/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Type/Abstract.php` on line 383

There is no server file size limit for my hosting

Comment: The error is about memory, not about file sizes. Have you already tried to increase `max_memory_limit` in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: No I didn't do anything

Comment: Looks like a problem related to the Module not Magento as the error is thrown from the Community Code Pool. You might want to take a look at the module page to see if it's a known problem. If not, then it's a PHP memory limit for sure. Try : ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

Comment: #    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000  these is my ht access code,I dont know how to reslove this problem